# Floor Plan implementation in Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i am in trouble in finding the best ways to crate a custom floorPlan for a exhibition where i can draw a path using A* algorithm between each exhibitor? I search a lot about this but dont get the right ways of building this.
Any help will be more appreciable

Floor Plan like [this](http://www.autumnfair.com/images/Flash_pra.jpg)

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: by implementing A* algorithm you can find path way-points, with the help of paint & canvas you can draw line between two points.

Comment: i edited the question pleas have a look..

Comment: Can you please check this [link] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N25MxHZ9dDE) and give me clue or guide me or help me to find tutorials. I'm trying to place some objects on real world coordinates through Android camera when I click.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Look at this [Google I/O App for Android](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/) .

**Guide yourself using the conference map**

**Note:** Well you only need to look at the Map portion of the code.

Comment: Can you please check this [link] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N25MxHZ9dDE) and give me clue or guide me or help me to find tutorials. I'm trying to place some objects on real world coordinates through Android camera when I click.